# Why does R xts plot only show a single column with nc=2?

Tags: r, plot, xts

On one machine, plot.xts correctly displays data in two columns:

[image: successful plot.xts]

On another, things look very different:

[image: failing plot.xts]

The code for both is the same:

```
library(zoo)
library(xts)
library(xtsExtra)
sessionInfo()
timezone = "UTC"
Sys.setenv(TZ=timezone)
sampleData = "Time (UTC),CPU,Runqueue,Blocked,MemoryFree,PageIns,ContextSwitches,Wait,Steal
2014-10-15 16:12:11,20,0,0,12222172,0,2549,0,0
2014-10-15 16:12:12,27,1,0,12220732,0,3619,0,0
2014-10-15 16:12:13,30,0,0,12220212,0,2316,0,0"
data = as.xts(read.zoo(text=sampleData, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", header=TRUE, sep=",", tz=timezone))
plot.xts(data, main="Title", minor.ticks=FALSE, yax.loc="left", auto.grid=TRUE, nc=2)
```

The output of the successful machine:

```
> library(zoo)

Attaching package: ‘zoo’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:

    as.Date, as.Date.numeric

> library(xts)
> library(xtsExtra)

Attaching package: ‘xtsExtra’

The following object is masked from ‘package:xts’:

    plot.xts

> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] xtsExtra_0.0-1 xts_0.9-7      zoo_1.7-11    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] grid_3.1.2      lattice_0.20-29
... The rest are just commands, no warnings/errors...
```

The output of the failing machine:

```
> library(zoo)

Attaching package: 'zoo'

The following objects are masked from 'package:base':

    as.Date, as.Date.numeric

> library(xts)
> library(xtsExtra)

Attaching package: 'xtsExtra'

The following object is masked from 'package:xts':

    plot.xts

> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
[1] C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets    methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] xtsExtra_0.0-1 xts_0.9-7      zoo_1.7-11    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
    [1] grid_3.1.2      lattice_0.20-29
... The rest are just commands, no warnings/errors...
```

The successful machine is local and the failing machine is remote with `export DISPLAY=${IP}:0` to the successful machine.

Why does R xts plot only show a single column with nc=2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As bergant mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/28571442/1293660, this is a bug in xtsExtra. After a binary search, revision #850 is the latest version that works:

```
$ svn checkout --revision 850 svn://svn.r-forge.r-project.org/svnroot/xts/
$ R
> install.packages("xts/pkg/xts", repos=NULL, type="source")
> install.packages("xts/pkg/xtsExtra", repos=NULL, type="source")
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to reproduce the different results using your script on the *same machine* - but using *different versions of xtsExtra*. The bad news is that the new version is giving the wrong result. This may be related to refactoring of xtsExtra/R/plot.R at [r-forge](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/xtsExtra/R/?root=xts).

Is it possible the package was installed more recently on the "failing machine"?

Comment: Hi, interesting! Yes, it was installed more recently on the "failing machine". Is there an older version I can download somewhere?

Comment: Confirmed. I updated the "good machine" to the latest xtsExtra and now it's also broken: `install.packages("http://download.r-forge.r-project.org/src/contrib/xtsExtra_0.0-1.tar.gz", repos=NULL, type="source")`

Comment: Opened bug https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=6029&group_id=118&atid=516

Comment: xtsExtra::plot.xts nor xts::plot.xts have arguments for `nc` and `yax.loc`. To plot multiple time series on different panels, see `?xts::plot.xts` and the `multi.panel` argument. You actually plotted the multiple time series on the same plot with the same y-axis although your data has very different ranges. That is why you see a line at the top and a line at the bottom of the chart.

Comment: I will look into changing the code to match the new API - `nc` and `yax.loc` used to exist in xtsExtra.

Answer (score 1):

```
plot.xts(data, main="Title", minor.ticks=FALSE, yax.loc="left", auto.grid=TRUE, nc=2)
```

see `?xts::plot.xts` and you will note that there are not arguments for `yax.loc` or `nc`. The `plot.xts` code was refactored this past summer and now the development of `plot.xts` is happening in the xts package.

Install xts rev 875 from R-Forge and try the following, this worked for me.

```
plot.xts(data, main="Title", multi.panel=TRUE, minor.ticks=FALSE, yax.right=FALSE)
```

Comment: Hi Ross, both `yax.loc` and `nc` are in `?xtsExtra::plot.xts` in revision 850, so it seems there was a major change. I will review `multi.panel`...

Comment: I checked out revision 875 and changed to the syntax above, and it's not working: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28611858/r-xtsplot-xts-multi-panel-doesnt-produce-data