# R xts::plot.xts multi.panel doesn't produce data

Tags: r, plot, xts

R's xtsExtra::plot.xts [no longer supports](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28597100/1293660) `nc` and `auto.grid`. I'm trying to use xts::plot.xts's `multi.panel` but the first problem is that all panels are blank:

```
$ svn checkout --revision 875 svn://svn.r-forge.r-project.org/svnroot/xts/
$ R
...
install.packages("xts/pkg/xts", repos=NULL, type="source")
library(zoo)
library(xts)
timezone = "UTC"
Sys.setenv(TZ=timezone)
sampleData = "Time (UTC),CPU,Runqueue,Blocked,MemoryFree,PageIns,ContextSwitches,Wait,Steal
2014-10-15 16:12:11,20,0,0,12222172,0,2549,0,0
2014-10-15 16:12:12,27,1,0,12220732,0,3619,0,0
2014-10-15 16:12:13,30,0,0,12220212,0,2316,0,0"
data = as.xts(read.zoo(text=sampleData, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", header=TRUE, sep=",", tz=timezone))
plot.xts(data, main="Title", multi.panel=TRUE, minor.ticks=FALSE, yax.right=FALSE)
```

[image: xts plot with multi.panel]

Comment: Revision 876 is the latest. Please upgrade. Also, I'm in the process of moving xts and xtsExtra from R-Forge to GitHub. Could you please wait to submit issues until I've finished the migration? I should be able to finish this weekend.